# Remote Desktop Close Automaticaly after Log In

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, windows-server

I have a Windows server 2012 inside of an active directory and I want to access it via remote desktop but I can´t. It ask me for the credentials when I try to connect, I can see the screen for a second while loading, and automatically closes remote desktop before load the desktop.

It only happens with that user in that machine the others users work well and the user who fails also works in the rest of Remote desktop Active directory machines so I don´t think that is a permission problem.

I try to remove the user profile using regedit but It´s the same, localy in the machine I can log in with the user who Fails in remote dekstop.

Comment: Try to find something in the Event Viewer. Try also to temporarily disable firewall and antivirus on that computer as test.

Comment: Thanks, finaly I had a GPO on AD that prevent that some users include this can log in to the machine